# fix soaplib to support chunked requests

Tags: python, web-services, soap, soaplib

I have soap webservice built with soaplib,
but if client sent chunked request it fails on 

`length = req_env.get("CONTENT_LENGTH")
body = input.read(int(length))`

because length is '' (empty string), any ideas how to fix soaplib?

Comment: What exactly are you seeing? And, if you think this is a legitimate bug, submit it to http://bugs.python.org. StackOverflow is not a bug tracker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a bit ugly, but looks like it works:

```
            if '' != length:
                body = input.read(int(length))
            elif req_env.get("HTTP_TRANSFER_ENCODING").lower() == 'chunked':

                chunk_size = int(input.readline(), 16)
                while chunk_size > 0:
                    chunk_read_size = 0
                    tmp  = input.read(chunk_size)
                    chunk_read_size += len(tmp)
                    body += tmp
                    while chunk_read_size
```